# How is Shinobi Bout played?

Tags: boruto

In Boruto, they play a card game called Shinobi Bout, where cards seem to have numbers and colors. It seems somewhat like the goal is to get rid of all of the cards in your hand. Is it ever explained how the game is played or what the rules are?

Comment: this may help you: http://kansaichick.com/japanese-kanji-blog/shinobi-bout-the-shinobi-card-game-in-boruto-part-2/

Answer (score 2):

It is essentially Uno with some small tweaks.
You are trying to play numbers, in order.  If you have a "run" of numbers in the same suit (color), you appear to be able to play them all at once.
There are cards that allow you to change the color, even a wild draw 4.
In the anime, you see Boruto play a change color card with a "skip" card skipping the next player's turn.  It appears the cards are numbered from 1-10 in five colors.